# ¿Se puede enviar un mensaje a otra IP local usando JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Me gustaría enviar mensajes entre dos páginas web en local usando JavaScript o algo similar. El problema que tengo es que en un dispositivo tengo una página web que espera a que en el otro dispositivo (con otra IP local) se rellene un formulario. Al rellenar el formulario me gustaría que de alguna manera se enviara un mensaje al primer equipo mediante JavaScript avisándole que ya finalizó el formulario.

He visto los websocket pero los servidores son en Java, node.js.... etc. Me gustaría saber si existe algún servidor en JavaScript o similar. Solo necesitaría enviar un mensaje avisando de que rellenó el formulario.

Gracias!

Comment: Nodejs es javascript, y creo que utilizar `socket` para solo eso no es necesario, siempre puedes utilizar `ajax` haciendo una petición confirme el formulario se ha rellanado ya te solucionaría el problema.

Comment: @EugeniBejan pero son dispositivos distintos, entonces sí sería necesario, no se sabe cuando el otro dispositivo a llenado el formulario, entonces sí haces la petición en ajax y no está lleno, pues no se hizo nada.

Comment: Supongamos que utiliza socket, entonces ¿Si no sabe cuando se va a rellenar el formulario como enviarías la señal socket al otro dispositivo? Yo doy por entendido que hay un algoritmo que controla eso, porque si no es muy difícil saberlo.

Comment: ¿Quieres hacer P2P con javascript? No es tan simple. En caso contrario, con el atributo action del formulario puedes apuntar al dispositivo que esta esperando y el mensaje se enviará al hacer submit.

Comment: @EugeniBejan El problema es ese, no se sabe exactamente cuando el usuario rellenará el formulario ni cuanto tiempo se tirará, por lo que lo único que se me ocurre es que una vez enviado el formulario este dispositivo envíe algún tipo de señal para avisar a la otra página web.

Comment: @Sal Lo que quiero es más parecido a un P2P. Cuando un usuario rellene un formulario y pulse enviar, que el dispositivo envíe algún tipo de señal, mensaje o similar para avisar a la otra página web que ya ha actualizado la información. ¿Se te ocurre alguna idea?  Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomeindo buscar mas informacion sobre [PeerJS](https://peerjs.com/) utiliza la [WebRTC API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API) de Javascript para crear conexiones Peer to Peer (P2P), pero utiliza un agente de conexión compartido.

Si quieres tu propio  agente de conexión, PeerJS provee el codigo de [PeerServer](https://github.com/peers/peerjs-server) para que puedas crear tu propia instancia on-premise.

Espero esto te sea de utilidad.